# jQuery Update Price from one div to another onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a price that changes on interval timings. I need to be able to update the margin of another div when this price changes.

Price 1: £10,000 (changes dynamically)

Price 2: £12,000

Price 3: £8,000

Calc: Price 2 - Price 1 = Price 3

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Layt8cuy/86/

```
$('.price1').change(function() {
  onTargetProfitChange()
});

function onTargetProfitChange(){
  var originalvalue = $(".price1").val();
}
```

Comment: How is the `$('.price1').change` function trigger.?? Do you have created a function to change the value.? and in your fiddle, there are many `.price1` so what is the play here.?

Comment: You can use `change` event only on form element, if a span text change it doesn't fire a `change` event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: On the fiddle i have a function and onChange, but not sure how and where to call it from, then work out the subtraction https://jsfiddle.net/Layt8cuy/86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all you will need to write a function to calculate the value of the `price3` i.e `onTargetChange()` and then call this function inside your `setInterval()`

Also I have added the class `active` to current div to get the current `price1` value...

Also `.val()` is used for `input` elements...here your value is inside `span`, so try to use `text()`...

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var currentDiv = $("#a");
var nextDiv, count = 1;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (count == 5) {
    return;
  } else {
    count++;
    currentDiv.removeClass("active").hide();
    currentDiv = currentDiv.next();
    currentDiv.addClass("active").show();
    onTargetChange();
  }
}, 3000);


function onTargetChange() {
  var price1Value = $(".active .price1").text();
  //console.log(price1Value);
  var price2Value = $(".price2").text();
  var price3Value = parseInt(price2Value) - parseInt(price1Value);
  $(".price3").text(price3Value);
}
```

```css
#b,
#c,
#d,
#e {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  When value from Price 1 changes. Price 3 needs to update.<br /> Calc: Price 2 - Price 1 = Price 3
</p>

<div id="a" class="active">
  <p>
    Price 1: £<span class="price1">12000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <p>
    Price 1: £<span class="price1">13000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="c">
  <p>
    Price 1: £<span class="price1">14000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="d">
  <p>
    Price 1: £<span class="price1">15000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="e">
  <p>
    Price 1: £<span class="price1">16000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Price 2: £<span class="price2">20000</span></p>

<hr />

<p>Price 3: £<span class="price3">8000</span></p>
```

Comment: Thats great, Thank you. When implementing this, when it loads in the last price, it shows "NaN", is it possible to get the commas in at all?

Comment: @John well with commas you will need to write some extra code to remove the `,` using `replace()` to do the calculation and then again to format it to show in the frontend....however you can try this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

Comment: Cheers, got the plugin working, only thing im struggling with is changing $ to £ and removing the decimal place so it reads £15,000 not $15,000.00 - any ideas? $('.price1').formatCurrency();

Comment: @John see now you are asking a new different question which is not the best way here in SO...I think you should post a new question....

Answer (score 0):

The change event doesn't trigger when the div content is changed. It only fires when form element changes. You will have to fire a custom event when Price 1 is changed.

Fire something like `$( ".price1" ).trigger( "change" );` when your Price 1 changes.

Then add an event handler like so `$( ".price1" ).on('change', function() {})` to catch the fired event.

Another idea is to create a hidden form element and track the change on that. You can update Price1 in the form field instead of  and then change the value in the  and handle other changes in the event handler.

**Update:**

Add `<input class="price-1-input" type="hidden" value="" />` to the top of your HTML.

Add `$('.price-1-input').val(currentDiv.find('.price1').text()).trigger('change');` in your interval function after `currentDiv = currentDiv.next();`

Format that numbers using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to do any calculations.

**Code:**

```js
var currentDiv = $("#a");
var nextDiv, count = 1;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (count == 5) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  } else {
    count++;
    currentDiv.hide();
    currentDiv = currentDiv.next();
    $('.price-1-input').val(currentDiv.find('.price1').text()).trigger('change');
    currentDiv.show();
  }
}, 3000);
    
 
// When Price 1 changes update new price

// Value of '#priceChange1' -'.price1'
$('.price-1-input').change(function() {
  onTargetProfitChange()
  console.log('changed')
});



function onTargetProfitChange(){
    var originalvalue = $(".price1").val();
}
```

```css
#b,
#c,
#d,
#e {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
When value from Price 1 changes. Price 3 needs to update.<br />
Calc: Price 2 - Price 1 = Price 3
</p>
<input class="price-1-input" type="hidden" value="" />
<div id="a">
  <p>
  Price 1: £<span class="price1">12,000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="b">
  <p>
  Price 1: £<span class="price1">13,000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="c">
  <p>
  Price 1: £<span class="price1">14,000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="d">
  <p>
  Price 1: £<span class="price1">15,000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="e">
  <p>
  Price 1: £<span class="price1">16,000</span>
  </p>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Price 2: £<span>20,000</span></p>

<hr />

<p>Price 3: £<span id="price3">8,000</span></p>
```

Comment: on the fiddle I have tried to do this... i think. Not sure where to add it to catch the onChange https://jsfiddle.net/Layt8cuy/86/

Comment: adding the hidden input as in the update works best.

Comment: Replace the 'change' event handler with this: `$('.price-1-input').change`